# Py4JJavaError for creating spark session

Tags: pyspark

I'm just trying to create spark session using the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark_session = SparkSession.builder\
                            .enableHiveSupport()\
                            .appName("spark sql1")\
                            .master("local")\
                            .getOrCreate()
```

and I've got the following error related to the APIs os the spark session

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-afe6b5baf64c> in <module>
      2                             .enableHiveSupport()\
      3                             .appName("spark sql1")\
----> 4                             .master("local")\
      5                             .getOrCreate()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    171                     for key, value in self._options.items():
    172                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 173                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    174                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
    175                     for key, value in self._options.items():

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    365         with SparkContext._lock:
    366             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 367                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    368             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    369 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    134         try:
    135             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 136                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    137         except:
    138             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    196 
    197         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 198         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    199         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    200         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    304         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    305         """
--> 306         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    307 
    308     @classmethod

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1523         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1524         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1525             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1526 
   1527         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(
```

and here is the definition of the error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:132)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:551)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1346)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:503)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:985)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:247)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:344)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This code was working before, I really don't know what happens so suddenly the code stop working, the anaconda environment is still as it is, without any change and pyspark is installed

Comment: I think that clue is here: `Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)!` - do you have other Spark instances running?

Comment: No, it's weird for me to stop working like that @AlexOtt

Comment: how do I know if there are other spark instances under the running ?! @AlexOtt

Comment: I have the exact same problem, have you figured this out yet